# PHP flush() not working via CLI script

Tags: php, command-line-interface, flush

My code:

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
@ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);
function show_status($done, $total, $size=30) {
    static $start_time;

    if($done > $total) return;

    if(empty($start_time)) $start_time=time();
    $now = time();

    $perc=(double)($done/$total);

    $bar=floor($perc*$size);

    $status_bar="[";
    $status_bar.=str_repeat("=", $bar);
    if($bar<$size){
        $status_bar.=">";
        $status_bar.=str_repeat(" ", $size-$bar);
    } else {
        $status_bar.="=";
    }

    $disp=number_format($perc*100, 0);

    $status_bar.="] $disp%  $done/$total";

    @$rate = ($now-$start_time)/$done;
    $left = $total - $done;
    $eta = round($rate * $left, 2);

    $elapsed = $now - $start_time;

    $status_bar.= " remaining: ".number_format($eta)." sec.  elapsed: ".number_format($elapsed)." sec.";

    echo "$status_bar\r";

    flush();

    if($done == $total) {
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

The call is simply show_status($count, $total_count); - its not working on my server for some reason, but I know the code above works (came from the net, and Ive used it before on another server). Problem Im having now on my current server is that its not outputting it per execution, only seeing the end result (100%) once its processed everything.

- Output buffering is set to Off (even though this shouldnt be needed because its being executed via CLI)
- zlib.output_compression set to Off
- see first 4 lines of code to other settings im trying to explicitly set as well
- Also have "SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary" in a .htaccess as this is apparently another cause of flush() not working

What am I missing!? This isnt a browser issue because once again, Im running this via the CLI!
PS: Im running this on WAMP with php 5.3.6 with apache 2.2.16

Comment: If you're running from the CLI, Apache is not handling anything, so you don't need to look inside .htaccess files as they only apply to files that are accessed via the browser.

Comment: What do you expect to see? If I remove the \r when you echo the status bar I get the status bar repeated however many times the function is called?

Comment: I just tried the above function on a new script on the same server and it worked! so its something script specific. Will give more details shortly...

Answer (score 2):

After looking into the script I believe there is nothing wrong with it. After running this test I was presented with a single line showing me the status at 8% complete:

```
show_status(10, 1000);
show_status(40, 1000);
show_status(80, 1000);
echo "\n";
```

However if I run this script:

```
show_status(10, 1000);
sleep(5);
show_status(40, 1000);
sleep(5);
show_status(80, 1000);
echo "\n";
```

The output line is periodically REPLACED ever 5 seconds with status 1%, 4%, 8%

I imagine what ever you are tracking the status of is simple completing far faster than the output is rendering and so you are seeing a completed result.

flush() has no effect on CLI.

Comment: Also its quite a nice little script. Where did you get it?

Comment: Yeah, it just randomly started working - so I dont know what was wrong where. Anway, thanks for the help. I found it online last year somewhere and made some tweaks to it.